# Avast Premier 2017 command line scanner for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, avast

Is it possible to configure avast command line scanner for the Avast Premier version?

Comment: Configure it in what way?

Answer (score 1):

No. [This feature](http://avast.helpmax.net/en/command-line-scanner/using-the-command-line/) is only available in **avast! Pro antivirus** and **avast! Internet Security**.